# Run Code as a different user

Tags: c#, impersonation, windows-authentication

Is there a way to tell my code to run as a different user?

I am calling NetUserSetInfo via a PInvoke and I need to call it as a different user.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Impersonation requires calling some native APIs (namely, LogonUser) so it's probably not worth posting 3 pages of wrapper code.  This page has a complete working sample: http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/

Note that impersonation has important security considerations.  Make sure you follow best practices.

Answer (score 31):

Probably the best and the cleanest [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/2108874) that I have seen so far is this:

```
var credentials = new UserCredentials(domain, username, password);
Impersonation.RunAsUser(credentials, logonType, () =>
{
    // do whatever you want as this user.
});
```

Just follow [Github](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation) or [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleImpersonation).

Comment: This certainly was easy to implement but I can't validate that it is working.  I do a process.start("cmd.exe") and the process still shows as owned by the ID that started the program not the impersonated ID.  What could I be missing?

Answer (score 11):

This [article](http://csharptuning.blogspot.com/2007/06/impersonation-in-c.html) explains it pretty succinctly:

Here's a code snippet from the article:

```
IntPtr accessToken = IntPtr.Zero;
....
//You have to initialize your accessToken with API calling 
....
WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(accessToken);
WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();
...
// Now your code is using the new WindowsLogin and you can do what ever this login can do
...

//Now you can return to your current login of Windows
context.Undo();
```