# C# Web service: want to execute shell command as Admin (or higher priv.)

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service which needs to execute a command on the server it's sitting on.  Specifically, I'm running the "net start [certain service]" command.  The problem lies in the permissions... the web service is running as NETWORK SERVICE, which doesn't have the appropriate permissions to execute this command.  Is there a way (possibly using Windows.Security) such that I can execute this as a higher privileged user.

** The command executes fine when ran locally, but this needs to be executed through the service (the point of the service...)

When attempting to impersonate a user, (using MSDN example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx):

> [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
>   static public string Impersonate(string userName, string domainName, string password)
>     {
>             IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
>         IntPtr dupeTokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
>             string output = "";
>         try 
>         {
>             const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
>             const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
>             output += "Set Token to ptrzero";
>             tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
>
> ```
>       output += "getting return value";
>       //Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token
>       bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName,
>                   password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, 
>                       LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref tokenHandle);
>
>       output += "LogonUser called";
>
>       if (!returnValue)
>       {
>           int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
>           output += "\n LogonUser failed with error code: " + ret.ToString();
>       }
>       else
>           output += "\nLogonUser succeeded!";
>
>       //check the identity:
>       output += "\n current: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
>
>       WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
>       WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
>
>       //Check:
>       output += "\n after: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
>   }   
>   catch (Exception ex)            
>   {
>   output += ex.ToString();            
>   } 
>   return output;
> ```
>
> }

I call the function to perform a shell execution, (Prior to execution I check if the current user is correct; which says the "current user" is my administrative-privileged account), but it still won't execute the same commands.

Comment: Your impersonation code looks OK, from memory. Check the output of `Environment.UserName` - it should match what `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returns.

Comment: Just checked the Environment.UserName, matches that of WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name... I'm stumped on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should impersonate an admin user: [Run Code as a different user (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168571/run-code-as-a-different-user-c)

By the way, you shouldn't need to shell out to the `net` command. The [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class can start and stop services.

Comment: I check the instance of servicecontroller's "CanPauseAndContinue", I get a false return... permission problem it seems.

Comment: Try `CanStop` - I've never seen a service that implements pause and continue functionality. Did you try impersonating?

Comment: CanStop also returns false, I'm trying to implement impersonating, so far no luck.

Comment: You could update your question with the details of how you're invoking impersonation, so someone could give you a hand. (Or maybe opening a second question would get more attention, if you get stuck.)

Comment: Sample code added above.  And thanks for continually checking on this Tim, it's greatly appreciated!