# Sharepoint execute powershellscript

Tags: c#, security, list, sharepoint, powershell

I need to excecute a PowerShell script from a `ListEventReceiver` under special User credentials. I found the `Runspace` which is working very fine to excecute scripts but how to make a secure (no passwords in the code) "run as"?

**Pipeline**

```
string cmdArg = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\userExist.ps1 " + mailstring;
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmdArg);
pipeline.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
var error = pipeline.Error.ReadToEnd();
runspace.Close();
```

I read about *secure store service* but I think it is only for whole services, pages or lists and can't be used for single functions?

Does any one have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to not just perform whatever the powershell script does in C# code?  Most of what you can do in powershell you can do directly in C#, and within C# privilege escalation is easy enough.

Comment: @Servy there are huge powershellscripts that already exist, so I would prefer to use them.

Comment: As far as storing secrets, the web.config connectionStrings section offers SharePoint code running in the context of a web application one very convenient option.  It's designed for connection strings, but ultimately it's just a key/value store with built in encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding running the script under another identity, have you tried [RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) yet?  If this doesn't do the trick it might be worth considering granting the application pool's account sufficent permisisons to complete the desired tasks.

Comment: Yes I already tried to RunWithElevatedPrivileges but with out success. The applications pool account can't get that permissions in ours environment.

Comment: It sounds to me as if this boils down to the more generic "how do I run my code as user X?"  This post addresses that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168571/run-code-as-a-different-user-c