# How to make my program run as administrator - Delphi xe5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I am trying to write my software so that it has administrator rights. Because it has to create files and be able to delete them, But if it is not started by right clicking on it, and clicking on run as administrator it is blocked from doing so.

Any solution would be great.

I did manage to find the following pages. But cannot make sense of it:

- [Run application with admin rights](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=209066)
- [How to give Administrator Rights to code?](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/500439/HowplustoplusgiveplusAdministratorplusRightsplusto)
- [Run Code as a different user (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168571/run-code-as-a-different-user-c)

**Update**

I'm trying to read files from the program files directory, and write them elsewhere.

Comment: Where are you writing these files?

Comment: @davidheffernan C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files\my applcation\

Comment: @davidHeffernan i am completely lost on that page, they seem to begin in the middle. 
I do not even know where to start

Comment: My advice is to stop writing to the program files directory. Then you won't need to add the manifest.

Comment: @davidHeffernan Ok but i do zip some files from the program files directory(not files i can move). Wont my program be blocked from gaining access to them then?

Comment: You cannot write there. But why do you want to write there. Write files in a location where you have rights. Users will soon get fed up of your program's UAC prompt.

Comment: As for the manifest. Do you know what one is? Do you know what an embedded resource is? If not then you first need to do some reading so that you understand all this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No i do not know, i have never worked with it. And i do not want to write there, i want to read from there and write to another location. Will i be blocked or can i read from there?

Comment: You can read from there fine. I suggest that you edit the question to include this new information.

Comment: Remember that not every user can run with elevate privileges. Your program will run if and only if a user can get those privileges, but not for "normal" users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It transpires in the comments that you are trying to read from the program files folder rather than write to it. In which case your program does not need elevation and can run as standard user. You do not need to add the UAC requireAdministrator manifest.